# Is "void" a scalar type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

On some sites I have found that `void` is a scalar type:

- https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap5/section2.1.3.html
- http://herbert.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/en/prgmsc1/docs/part2a.pdf
- https://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-data-types/

Other sites contain no information about this:

- https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/LinkedDS01CD/page_03.htm
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFDt3.png

Is `void` a scalar type or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `void` **is not** considered a scalar type.  It is actually an incomplete type.

Section 6.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Types" states the following regarding `void` in paragraph 19:

> The `void` type  comprises  an  empty  set  of  values;  it  is  an  incomplete  object  type  that cannot be completed.

And paragraph 21 defines scalar types as:

> Arithmetic  types  and  pointer  types  are  collectively  called *scalar  types*.  Array  and structure types are collectively called
>   *aggregate types*.

Answer (score 7):

From the C18 standard (6.2.5 §21) :

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called *scalar types*.

`void` is neither an arithmetic type, nor a pointer type, so it's not a scalar type.

From 6.2.5 §19 :

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a special type category of its own. It is not a scalar type, but an incomplete type that you cannot declare an instance of.

From C17 6.2.5:

§18

> Integer and floating types are collectively called *arithmetic types*.

§19

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
>   cannot be completed.

§21

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called *scalar* types.